# How to pass the content of a file to Helm values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I want to use Helm chart of RabbitMQ to set up a cluster but when I try to pass the configuration files that we have at the moment to the values.yaml it doesn't work.

The command that I use:

```
helm install --dry-run --debug stable/rabbitmq --name testrmq --namespace rmq -f rabbit-values.yaml
```

rabbit-values.yaml:

```
rabbitmq:
  plugins: "rabbitmq_management rabbitmq_federation rabbitmq_federation_management rabbitmq_shovel rabbitmq_shovel_management rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_web_stomp rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s"
  advancedConfiguration: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "rabbitmq.config" | quote}}
```

And what I get for `advancedConfiguration`:

```
NAME:   testrmq
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Thu Aug 29 10:09:26 2019
CHART: rabbitmq-5.5.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
rabbitmq:
  advancedConfiguration: '{{ .Files.Get "rabbitmq.config" | quote}}'
  plugins: rabbitmq_management rabbitmq_federation rabbitmq_federation_management
    rabbitmq_shovel rabbitmq_shovel_management rabbitmq_mqtt rabbitmq_web_stomp rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s
```

I have to mention that:

- rabbitmq.config is an Erlang file
- I tried different things including indentation (`indent 4`)

Comment: you are trying to call .Files.Get inside a values file, which is not parsed as a template

Comment: see [this issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/5491)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't use Helm templating in the `values.yaml` file.  (Unless the chart author has specifically called the `tpl` function when the value is used; for this variable [it doesn't](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/rabbitmq/templates/configuration.yaml#L21), and that's usually called out in the chart documentation.)

Your two options are to directly embed the file content in the `values.yaml` file you're passing in, or to use the

- [Helm `--set-file` option](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) (link to v2 docs)
- [Helm `--set-file` option](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/) (link to v3 docs).

```bash
helm install --dry-run --debug \
     stable/rabbitmq \
     --name testrmq \
     --namespace rmq \
     -f rabbit-values.yaml \
     --set-file rabbitmq.advancedConfig=rabbitmq.config
```

There isn't a way to put a file pointer inside your local values YAML file though.

Comment: In case anyone comes wondering how to pass a nested file name with `--set-file`, the key is also in the docs: "_Sometimes you need to use special characters in your `--set` lines. You can use a backslash to escape the characters_" - e.g. `--set-file 'configFiles.config\.toml'=custom-config.toml` will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

As this is google top result, here is some related issue with the solution:

I have some chart, that has a subchart as well as a config folder. I want to pass the content of the config folder down to the subchart, to be used as some file based configmap.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
...
data:
{{ if .Values.files}}
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.files }}
    {{ $k }}:
     {{ $v | indent 2}}
{{- end }}
{{end}}
```

and calling `helm` with this beauty:

```bash
helm ...  $(for i in $(ls config/); do echo --set-file mySubChart.files.${i//./\\.}=config/$i;done)"
```

Thanks to @Alfageme for the hint about the dot.